# How to use the Hostname for the AWS Lambda when it is the ALB target

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, aws-serverless

I am setting up a Lambda, which is the target for a ALB. This lambda is a **nodejs**, **express**, serverless-http application, which renders a html document using 'pug' view engine. When the request is made to a host '*app.myhost.com/news*' the ALB forwards the request to my lambda. But my requested URL with the ALB hostname is **replaced** by Lambda's url 'https://lambda-id.region.amazonaws.com/stage/news'.

My question is how do I **retain** the 'app.myhost.com/news' url, when the html document is rendered in the browser, the user sees my site name in the url.

I tried to look for some header which ALB writes when the request was forwarded to my lambda, like x-forwarded header, but nothing has this original hostname.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!